# IE doesn't load css files

Tags: html, css, asp.net, internet-explorer, iis-7.5

I've Asp.net MVC solution that was developed by another company installed on a IIS 7.5.

The site is running just fine - but the CSS styles isn't loaded when I open the site inside IE 10 / IE 11.

When using Google Chrome the CSS styles is applied as expected and everyone is happy - expect my boss. He wants the solution to work in IE.

I can't figure out what is going wrong.

I've have looked at the source for the page and tried to copy the link into a new browser tab - I get a response.

The site is included into "Trusted Sites", the Security Settings for "Trusted Sites" is dropped to the lowest possible. The site has also been included into the "Compatibility Mode".

The solution is developed in Visual Studio 2013, .NET 4.5. I don't know how to see what MVC version is used - I've only developed WebForms. When running the site from VS2013 with the debugger enabled on my local machine IE shows the pages perfectly.

The solution tries to implement bundling of the script files to avoid the limitation of the total links to CSS / javascript files.

```
 public class BundleConfig
{
    // For more information on bundling, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301862
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

        // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
        // ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                  "~/Scripts/respond.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/custom").Include(
                "~/Scripts/custom.js",
                "~/Scripts/custom.js"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                  "~/Content/site.css"));

        BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true; 
    }
}
```

I hope some of you guys can point me in the correct direction.

Comment: Are you running Chrome in dev? It shouldn't matter which browser you use. If web resources aren't available, it is for all browsers.

Comment: Resources aren't _loaded_ or styles _not applied_?

Comment: Sorry for the late response.

I don't know the difference between not loaded or not applied. From what I can see it looks like the styles are not applied. I can post some screenshots if it helps.